# How to add data to CKEditor using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Everytime a page loads I need to load text into the CK Editor using JQuery, in order to get data from CK Editor I use

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
```

now is there a similar function I could use to put the data back into the editor?

I'm using ajax to set the data like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/inc/ajax/basic.php?menu_id="+menu_id+"&info=3",
  success: function(msg){

    CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(msg);
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Your title says FCKEditor, but the question is talking about CKEditor; they are actually two separate projects. Which one are you asking about here?

Comment: Explaining about importance of setData() method, when using CKeditor with a `<textarea>`: the `&gt;` and `&lt;` entities are converted to tag simbols, see http://jsfiddle.net/9qu39/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(html)
```

Where 'html' is a string containing content to edit.

Comment: This is the correct thing to do, but it just does not want to work in this case

$.ajax({

      type: "POST",

      url: "/inc/ajax/basic.php?menu_id="+menu_id+"&info=3",

      success: function(msg){

 
     

     

        CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(msg);

       
        
      }

  });

Comment: Explaining about importance of setData() method, when using CKeditor with a `<textarea>`: see http://jsfiddle.net/9qu39/

Answer (score 11):

Because its not an array then 
just replace the instance like this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.help_ldesc;         
editor.setData(''); 
$.ajax({
url: urlstr, // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data:{action:"ex_form"}, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache:false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
    //alert(data);
    var data1=data.split("~`");
    $('#help_id').val(data1[0]);
    $('#help_title').val(data1[1]);
    $('#help_sdesc').val(data1[2]);                 

    editor.setData(''+data1[3]);    
    var edata = editor.getData();
    alert(edata);
}
});
```

Use this code its works for me and (help_ldesc) is my textarea name.

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.instances['<%=ckEditor.ClientID%>'].setData(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use data,  and method for sending query string like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var querystring="menu_id="+menu_id+"&info=3";
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/inc/ajax/basic.php",
  data:querystring,
  success: function(msg)
   {
     CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(msg);
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "file.php", function(data) {
CKEDITOR.instances.idOftextAreaName.setData( data );
    alert( "success" );
  })
.done(function() {
    //alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
   // alert( "finished" );
});
```

Comment: change idOftextAreaName to id of your textarea .

Comment: Welcome! Note that you can also click [edit] below your answer and update. This is preferred over leaving comment on own answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using inside a function sometimes doesn't work properly. I'll suggest to use in:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    //set data
    CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(data);
    ...
    });
```