# How to load a local HTML file on CKEditor 4.3 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.3 on my html page, and I want to read a local html page and put it on the CKEditor. (i am brazilian = bad english :P)

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editor').ckeditor(function(){
        var editor = $('#editor').ckeditorGet();

        // Capturando o conteúdo do editor
        var data = $('#editor').val();
        // Adicionando conteúdo ao editor
        $('#editor').val('load("Home.htm")');
    },
    {
        width: 780,
        height: 350
    });
});
```

Comment: For starters, remove the quotes around your functon call in `val()`, then you can check the console, _if_ there's an error message telling you, [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) can't be used to read local files.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117859/386579

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `'load("Home.htm")'` to load the data, try [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("Home.htm").done(function (data) {
    // Do something with the data
    $('#editor').val(data);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i have done this:       
$('#editor').load('Home.htm');
$('#editor').ckeditor();

  i load the textarea with the htm file and then i replace it with the editor